# Coloring techniques in Angry Birds

Tags: color, games

Are there any particular coloring techniques or principles that are used in the popular game Angry Birds?

I've noticed the number of colors used on each colored area is four, most of the time. A base color, then shadows and highlights, and a little bit of glow

Are those colors related somehow? Could these be generated programmatically as a color pallete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's basically a minimalist approach to depth.

- Color + 25% white = highlight
- Color + 25% black = shadow

or

- Base color = color at 70% saturation
- Highlight = color at 50% saturation
- Shadow = color at 100% saturation

Then you only need to alter the base color. I do this a great deal in illustrations. It keeps all shadows and highlights at the same level of intensity regardless of the base color.

I would not know of a programatic method to generate such a system. But I can't imagine it would be too difficult.

Comment: ok, I see what you say... varying saturation over the base color at predefined levels, will do the trick on photoshop
I'll try bright/contrast too, and combinations, to see what happens